# Install Font-awesome through bower but font is not working

Tags: bower, font-awesome

I install font awesome sass through bower, define all path properly and correct.

```
@import "../font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

but when I run gulp its showing rectangle icon, when I put css file direct to HTML file then its working fine, Even when I check compiled css file then all path is correct.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0");
  src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

It means font is not loading. 
anyone know why?